# Is there a way to display calendar notifications without having to unlock the screen?

Tags: calendar, lock-screens

For SMS there is an application called SMS popup which will display the message over the lock-screen.

Is there anything similar for calendar notifications that allows you to clear or snooze the notification without having to unlock the screen?

Comment: what's the point of having a lock screen if you can circumvent it? :)

Comment: @LouisRhys the point of having a lock screen is to protect private data from being visible if I lost my phone. For me the easy access to the calendar is more important. That's why I have the same question. There are different kind of data. I write my diary on the phone. I want it to be only accesible by me, but calendar is not top secret.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WidgetLocker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/widgetlocker-lockscreen/com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker) is a great lock-screen replacement that will allow you to put any widget installed on your phone on the lock-screen.  You can also configure it to allow your Notification bar to be usable.  The actual calendar popup I'm not sure about, but I know you'd be able to see it when it shows up in your notification bar, and from there you can open it up and snooze/dismiss it.

Comment: This app does not exist any more :-(

Answer (score 1):

This works: [Your Calendar Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mash.android.calendar)